# for loops and iterating through lists - how does "for a[-1] in a:" work?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

Here is a snippet of code which gives the output: `0 1 2 2`. I had expected the output `3 3 3 3` since `a[-1]` accesses the number 3 in the list. The explanation given online says "The value of `a[-1]` changes in each iteration" but I don't quite understand how or why. Any explanations would be great!

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

Comment: I have never seen anything like that; I'd love to read the article / tutorial / whatever it is that shows this example, could you please post link to it?

Comment: Also, congratulations for nice first question! (faith in new SO users restored)

Comment: Nice question. Why is `a[-1]` even allowed as the loop variable...

Comment: Straight-up funniest for-loop I've ever seen.

Comment: @timgeb because it **is not** "a loop variable"; it is an assignment target, and Python uses the same syntax for assigning to elements (and slices) that it does for rebinding names. (I have been slowly coming to the conclusion that this was the *actual* major design mistake here.)

Comment: "The explanation given online says" - **where** was this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What's happening here is a list is mutated during looping.

Let's consider following code snippet:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print a
```

Output is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
```

Each iteration:

- reads value from position currently pointed by internal pointer
- immediately assigns it to last element in list
- after that last element is printed on standard output

So it goes like:

- internal pointer points to first element, it's 0, and last element is overwritten with that value; list is `[0, 1, 2, 0]`; printed value is `0`
- internal pointer points to second element, it's 1, and last element is overwritten with that value; list is `[0, 1, 2, 1]`; printed value is `1`
- (...)
- at last step, internal pointer points to last element; last element is overwritten by itself - list does not change on last iteration; printed element also does not change.

Answer (score 39):

While doing `for a[-1] in a`, you actually iterate through the list and temporary store the value of the current element into `a[-1]`.

You can see the loop like these instructions:

```
a[-1] = a[0] # a = [0, 1, 2, 0]
print(a[-1]) # 0
a[-1] = a[1] # a = [0, 1, 2, 1]
print(a[-1]) # 1
a[-1] = a[2] # a = [0, 1, 2, 2]
print(a[-1]) # 2
a[-1] = a[3] # a = [0, 1, 2, 2]
print(a[-1]) # 2
```

So, when you are on the third element, then `2` is stored to `a[-1]` (which value is `1`, but was `0` before and `3` on start).

Finally, when it comes to the last element (and the end of the iteration), the last value stored into `a[-1]` is `2` which explains why it is printed twice.

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

is equivalent to

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for i in range( len(a) ):
    a[-1] = a[i] # update last element of list(updated) with element at i'th position
    print(a[-1]) # print last element of list
```

the output will be 0 1 2 2

Explanation:

len(a) = 4, range( len(a) ) = [0, 1, 2, 3]

- 1st loop, current list = [0, 1, 2, 3], i = 0 => a[i] = a[0] = 0, updated list = [0, 1, 2, 0], last element **a[-1] = 0**
- 2nd loop, current list = [0, 1, 2, 0], i = 1 => a[i] = a[1] = 1, updated list = [0, 1, 2, 1], last element **a[-1] = 1**
- 3rd loop, current list = [0, 1, 2, 1], i = 2 => a[i] = a[2] = 2, updated list = [0, 1, 2, 2], last element **a[-1] = 2**
- 4th loop, current list = [0, 1, 2, 2], i = 3 => a[i] = a[3] = 2, updated list = [0, 1, 2, 2], last element **a[-1] = 2**