# Difference between 'for a[-1] in a' and 'for a in a' in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, python-internals

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695538/python-for-loop-and-iterating-through-lists), the following code snippets could work.

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695599/3011380)

> While doing `for a[-1] in a`, you actually iterate through the list and temporary store the value of the current element into `a[-1]`.

Likewise, I think doing `for a in a`, it should iterate through the list and temporary store the value of current element to `a`, so the value of `a` could be `0`, and is not iterable, then `TypeError` exception will be thrown in the next iteration. However, the result is as below.

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> for a in a:
...     print a
... 
0
1
2
3
>>> a
3
```

How to understand it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the [official documentation on `for` loop](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement),

> **An iterator is created for the result of the expression_list**. The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the iterator, in the order of ascending indices.

So, when you are iterating an object, an iterator object is created and that is used for iteration. That is why the original object is not lost, at least till the loop runs.

In your case, when `for a in a:` is executed, an iterator object is created for `a` first, and the values are retrieved from the iterator object. Even though the loop binds the name `a` to some other value on each iteration, the iterator object still holds reference to the original list object and it gives out values from it. That is why you are not getting any error.

Comment: So `a[-1]` could change the `iterator object`?

Comment: @zangw It doesn't change the iterator object, it actually changes the value in the list object. When the iterator reaches the last element, it simply returns whatever is there in the last position of the list.

Comment: since the `iterator object` is created in the `for` iteration, `a[-1]` change the original object, but `for a in a:` just change the `iterator object`?

Comment: @zangw The iterator object will be created before the for loop begins. Basically `for a in a:` is actually `for a in iter(a):`. So, the values retrieved from the iterator are bound to `a` in each iteration.

Comment: When I say bound, think of it is assignment operation. So, in each iteration, a value from the iterator is retrieved and stored in `a`. But this simply makes `a` to have a different value, but the original list object pointed by `a`, will be still in memory, as the iterator object is still using it.

Comment: @zangw No problem at all :-) Since English is not my native language, I might not have been able to express what I actually I meant properly. Thanks for bearing with my English :-)