# Using index reference in a for loop iterations

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop

The output of the following code is:

> 0,1,2,2

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

How `a[-1]` become `0` in first loop iteration?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? what is it you want the code to do?

Comment: I came across this code in an online tutorial. I found the answer just now
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695538/for-loops-and-iterating-through-lists/34695599#34695599

Comment: I was just about to answer the question for you! Glad you found out though.

Comment: Thank you very much