# 'For loop' with list indexing

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
```

I cant understand why the last list has last element as 2 ?? I only want to understand the logic that how this 'for loop' is working, when used with indexing ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because each iteration you're assigning to the last element of the list `a`. So on the last iteration the last element is `2` (from previous iteration).

Comment: Better explanation than the linked duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695538/for-loops-and-iterating-through-lists/34695599#34695599

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks, that's the one I couldn't find again. I edited the duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

The iteration goes as follows:

for i in range(0 , len(a)):
print the list a , and in each iteration , reduce the value at a[-1] by 1 , which in this case is the last element(that's how negative indexing works)

Comment: um, no, that isn't what is happening.